# Assigning values to patches in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am an absolute beginner to Netlogo, using it for the purpose of making models relevant to studies in archaeology. I'm trying to model 2 communities competing for resources, the "resources" being differently colored patches. My question is - how can I assign a "value" for a given patch? I want some patches to be more "valuable" than others (e.g blue patches better than red patches), and am wondering how does one go about assigning numerical values to them, regarding numbers as a "materialistic value scale"?

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorials on the NetLogo site or any of the models in the model library included with NetLogo? Patches each have their own set of variables. Some are built in (like `pcolor` for colour) and some are created by the modeller with a `patches-own` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JenB commented above you can create a new variable with a value for each patch by declaring the variable in a "patches-own []" section of your code, which goes up at the top before the "setup" section.   Then you can declare initial values for these in the "setup" section and read/write values in the "go" section.

;; Here's an oversimplified example

```
patches-own [ my-value ]  ;; Give every patch a place to store a new variable
                          ;; which we will name "my-value"
to setup
clear-all   

print "---------------- starting a new run ---------------" ;; if you want to see this  
;; do whatever you do
;; let's create some patches and set various patch colors ("pcolor")

  ask N-of 100 patches [set pcolor red]
  ask N-of 100 patches [set pcolor blue]

;; After they are created you should initialize the values of my-value
;;   or you could get sloppy and trust they will always initialize to zero

;; If there are lots of different colors there are nicer ways to do this
;; but if it's just red and blue we could simply do the following.  We will
;; give blue patches a value of 500 and red patches a value of 300

ask patches [
   if pcolor = blue [set my-value 500]
   if pcolor = red  [set my-value 300]
]
; ... whatever else you have in setup
reset-ticks   
end

;; Then your go section can just refer to these values the same way as you refer to
;; patch colors (pcolor). Say you just want a count of high values of "my-value"

to go
  if (ticks > 5) [   ;; or whatever your stopping condition is
    print "------- time has run out, stopping the run! ----"
    print " "
    stop
  ]    ;; just so this won't run forever

 ;... whatever

   type "the count of patches with my-values > 300 is now " 
   print count patches with [my-value > 300] 

;... whatever 
; For this example, let's change some random blue patch from blue to red
; and as we do that, set my-value to an appropriate value

  ask n-of 1 patches with [pcolor = blue][
    set pcolor red 
    set my-value 300
  ]

tick   
end
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Wade and JenB! I did try looking into existing models within the library, just had a hard time understanding exactly the principles behind them and behind patches-own. Wade explained it perfectly!